# JS/HTML5/Meteor How to change an input to a label?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I have an input form in html, like this:

```
<input type = "text" id ="name" placeholder = "Name"/>
```

I can change the "placeholder" value with:

```
document.getElementById('name').placeholder = Session.get("username")
```

After setting the username to the initial input, but I want to actually change the input into a label (let's say a p tag with strong) with Session.get("username") as its value. How?

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of reactivity and templates to achieve what you need the Meteor way.

template_name.html

```
<template name="template_name">
    {{#if username}}
        <p><strong>{{username}}</strong></p>
    {{else}}
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" required />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

template_name.js

```
Template.template_name.helpers({
    username:function(){
        return Session.get("username");
    }
});

Template.template_name.events({
    "submit form":function(event,template){
        event.preventDefault();
        var username=template.find("input[name='username']").value;
        Session.set("username",username);
    }
});
```

When your template will first render, the username helper will be undefined and the else branch will display the input.
When you later set the Session variable after validating user input, it will rerender and display it inside a label.

Comment: I'm getting a     

"submit form":function(event, template){
SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Any ideas?

Comment: Just created an empty project to test my piece of code : it works as expected without any syntax error, so the problem must come from another part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replaceChild()` and `document.createElement()`:

```
var newP = document.createElement('p'),
    newStrong = document.createElement('strong'),
    text = document.createTextNode(Session.get('username')),
    input = document.getElementById('name');

newStrong.appendChild(text);
newP.appendChild(newP);
input.parentNode.replaceChild(newP, input);
```

References:

- [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).
- [`Node.replaceChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.replaceChild).

Answer (score 0):

You could use reactivity:

Your JS (client side)

```
Template.hello.placeholder = function() {
    return Session.get("username");
}
```

Your HTML

```
<template name="hello">
    <input type = "text" id ="name" placeholder = "{{placeholder}}"/>
</template>
```

As soon as you change it with `Session.set("username",`new value`)` the new value will be applied reactively.